# Seperate lambda query into new method

Tags: c#, lambda

Below is two class I writed:

```
class a {
    public void getEntities(){
         B b = new b();
         List<entity> entities = b.select(c=>c.id==5);
         // more detail
    }
}

class b {
    public List<entity> Select( LambdaExpression expression){
        return _dbSet.where(expression).ToList();
    }
}
```

But system tell me the `LambdaExpression expression`is invalid.
Now how can I define the select method?
Thanks

Comment: You're not even referencing the correct member function. C# is case sensitive, "Select" != "select".

Comment: -1 This code clearly does not even compile. Please write a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Use .net coding convention whenever possible. `B b = new b();` can clearly NEVER compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a delegate of type [`Func`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) passed as parameter.

In your case `Func<entity, bool>` the first will be the parameter type and the second is the return type (`(c) => c.id==5`). `Where` expects to return a `bool`.

```
class a {
    public void getEntities(){
         b b = new b();
         List<entity> entities = b.Select(c=>c.id==5);
         // more detail
    }
}

class b {
    public List<entity> Select(Func<entity, bool> expression){
        return _dbSet.Where(expression).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Note:** As @Amit mentioned too, you must correct the `Linq` extensions to be [camel case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx).

Comment: Or, in case of nhibernate an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

Comment: @knittl You are perfectly right, he didn't mentioned something about `NHibernate`, yet.